# How to skip error checking when compiling Scala files in IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

The run config option `Make, no error check` in IntelliJ IDEA does not skip Scala errors that result in ambiguous ClassDefNotFound errors upon running a project.

How do I skip error checking when compiling Scala files?

My end goal is for the program to fail at runtime when the classes with errors are accessed, *not before* runtime preventing the whole program from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, "Make, no error check" will just pretend compile errors don't matter. Then obviously you end up with an incomplete class path, not containing any classes that produce compiler errors. As a consequence, when you run that project, you should not be surprised to find class-not-found errors.

I don't know how this "feature" interacts with the incremental Scala compiler. I wouldn't expect "Make, no error check" to produce *any* useful results.

If you want to skip parts of your code that currently don't compile, a good solution is to use the `???` "hole" value, i.e. a placeholder of type `Nothing` that you can plug into any position where you would have incomplete code. E.g.

```
def myMethod: String = ??? // implement later
```

This allows these things to be compiled and will only produce runtime errors when hit during runtime.

Comment: It is technically a solution so I one-upped it, but this is nowhere near as trivial as the Java solution to make with no error check.  Could it be that this needs to be handled by the scala plugin for intellij team?  Or is there an equivalent compiler option that can be used?